# Background of default template showing instead of the background of custom page template

Tags: page-template, wp-enqueue-style, wp-head

Plugins were not working for my custom page template, found out that I needed to put WP_head() and WP_footer(), so did that and the plugins started to work. But now the background changed to that of the default template.

If I remove wp_head(), the custom template's background comes back, but plugins do not work anymore. If I use get_header(), logos, menus,background, etc. floods the custom page template, which I don't want.

Please help.

#### Edit

Custom page template code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: OldSkool
*/
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Salesletter Template</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/OldSkool-src/style.css">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #000000;
}
.style2 {color: #FF0000}
.style3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333333;
}
.style4 {color: #990000}
.style4 {   font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.style9 {font-size: 16px}
.style7 {font-weight: bold; color: #990000; font-size: 18px;}
.style10 {color: #999999}


</style>
<?php
function mypage_head() {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/OldSkool-src/style.css">'."\n";
}
add_action('wp_head', 'mypage_head');
?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">

  </div>
   <div id="content">
     <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;'); ?>    


    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

        <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>

        <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
      <strong><?php wp_footer(); ?><a href="http://www.planstoprosperity.com" style="color:#FFFFFF" target="_blank"><font color="#FFFFFF"></a></font></strong>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide code examples, as well as how you are defining your background, there is much you're assuming that we are unaware of and cannot see ( we're not psychic! )

Comment: Downvote for lack of code, rendering this question impossible to answer. Will remove if question is edited to include relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Downvote removed. See answer below!

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, the issue is where/how you're outputting your custom stylesheet.

First, move this to functions.php:

```
function mypage_head() {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/OldSkool-src/style.css">'."\n";
}
add_action('wp_head', 'mypage_head');
```

Second, change the action into which you're hooking your callback.

You're using `wp_head`. All other stylesheets will be using `wp_print_styles`. The `wp_print_styles` action fires *inside of* the `wp_head` action, and will fire *after* your callback that is hooked directly into `wp_head`.

So change this:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'mypage_head');
```

...to this (note the decreased priority, which will cause it to output later than everything firing at the default priority of `10`):

```
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'mypage_head', 11 );
```

Note: if this *still* doesn't work, then we'll need to know what hook the Plugin is using to output its sytlesheet, as at that point, the problem will be that the Plugin is using a priority greater than 10, or is using a different action hook.

Comment: Please refer to my Before/After images of the Custom Page Template (OldSkool) and the Default Template (Mainstream). The Before images are when I have not added anything to either the OldSkool.php or functions.php. After images are when I added the codes as per your guidance.

Before images - 
[link](http://s11.postimage.org/bzv12z31v/Old_Skool_Template_Before.jpg)[link](http://s12.postimage.org/3nkktobcd/Default_Template_Before.jpg.) 

After images - 
[link](http://s11.postimage.org/div0loz03/Old_Skool_Template_After.jpg)
[link](http://s14.postimage.org/ngczaua3l/Default_Template_After.jpg)

Comment: What is the **desired outcome**? And can we get a live link of the rendered output?

Comment: Here are the links:
[link](http://www.planstoprosperity.com/financial_plan/)
[link](http://www.planstoprosperity.com)

I want the "CLICK LIKE & GET YOUR FREE FINANCIAL PLAN" to be centered in the page within a colored button, which I have set in the settings of the plugin wp-like-locker. When someone clicks the facebook Like button below, a hidden content is shown. Both of these are not working at present. And as you can see the webpage is not rendered correctly.

Comment: Where are those styles defined? Inline stylesheet, or linked stylesheet? If linked: which stylesheet link?

Comment: Styles are defined at wp-content/themes/mainstream/OldSkool-src/style.css

Comment: It appears your stylesheet output is being minimized by W3TC. Can you disable this Plugin?

Comment: On deactivating the W3TC plugin, the background of [link](http://www.planstoprosperity.com/financial_plan/) became blue as needed. But the other pages remained messed up. Please look at [link](http://www.planstoprosperity.com/)

Comment: Okay, now: if your *desired* style definitions are defined in `style.css`, in what stylesheet are the *overriding* style definitions? (And which Plugin is adding that stylesheet?)

Comment: The custom page template [link](http://www.planstoprosperity.com/financial_plan/) uses wp-content/themes/mainstream/OldSkool-src/style.css. I don't understand which stylesheet the mainstream theme uses. There are 3 stylesheets at wp-content/themes/mainstream/ which are custom.css,reset.css and style.css. There are other stylesheets inside wp-content/themes/mainstream/styles folder containing blue.css,default.css,etc. I don't understand what you meant by "which Plugin is adding that stylesheet". Are the 2 style.css causing this issue? But they are in different folders, aren't they?

Comment: Perhaps a plugin *didn't* add the overriding styles. Perhaps the overriding styles are part of the Theme itself. Regardless: which stylesheet has the *overriding* styles? We need to figure that out, so that we can then figure out how that stylesheet is being enqueued.

Comment: My desired style definitions for my custom page at [link](http://www.planstoprosperity.com/financial_plan/)is at wp-

content/themes/mainstream/OldSkool-src/style.css. My desired style definitions for the other pages of the site are at   wp-content/themes/mainstream/style.css. So the styles defined at wp-

content/themes/mainstream/OldSkool-src/style.css seems to be overriding the styles defined at wp-content/themes/mainstream/style.css for the other pages of the site.

Comment: The `/mainstream/style.css` file isn't being linked *at all* on that page, while the `/mainstream/Old-Skool-src/style.css` file is being linked **three times**. At this point, you'll probably need to post (or Pastebin) your `functions.php` file, and I am starting to lean toward this question being *too localized*.

Comment: I have pastebinned the functions.php here-[link](http://pastebin.com/XzN6paN8). Thanks for all your help.

Comment: There is one stylesheet callback in `functions.php`. You'll need to find where else the Theme is adding callbacks to hook in stylesheets.